# What happens when duplicate question is edited?

Tags: support

What happens when you edit a duplicate question?

I have a [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/406036/echo-into-a-file-while-maintaining-escaped-spaces) marked duplicate but the linked answer doesn't help.

I've edited my question and title, to try make what I'm asking more clear.

What happens now will my question go into a queue to be checked again or does something only happen if someone looks by chance and decides to unmark it?

Comment: The answer you accepted is a one-line summary of the accepted answer in the duplicate, so why don't you think it's a duplicate?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the circumstances. In this case, you edited the question within 5 days of it being closed, which pushes it into the reopen review queue (you can see it [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/218869)). Since it's your question, you should also be able to [vote to reopen it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes), which would also cause it to show up in the review queue if it weren't already.